# az storage container list. doesnt work, referencing deleted storage

Tags: azure

I am following this tutorial, running az cli(v 2.11) on my MacOS locally:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/provision-infrastructure-azure-pipelines/6-run-terraform-remote-storage

after following a few steps including this one:

`az storage account create --name tfsa$UNIQUE_ID --resource-group tf-storage-rg --sku Standard_LRS`

and have run this command:

`az storage container list --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv`

i receive the following:

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mystorageaccount20822.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?comp=list&maxresults=5000 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10d2566a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))`

The above command works in cloud shell, but fails in my local shell (running v 2.20, up to date)

on cloud shell i *do* get this warning though:

> There are no credentials provided in your command and environment, we
> will query for the account key inside your storage account. Please
> provide --connection-string, --account-key or --sas-token as
> credentials, or use `--auth-mode login` if you have required RBAC
> roles inyour command. For more information about RBAC roles in
> storage, visit
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli.

I had previously created a mystorageaccount20822 a couple weeks ago but deleted it... my AZ CLI is still bound to this previous account? Is there a way to tell my az cli (on mac) to sync up with the current resources i have running. In Azure Portal mystorageaccount20822 does NOT exist.

Does Azure CLI cache some values or something? is there some hidden config file that has the old 'mystorageaccount20822' set and the CLI is trying to reference that each time instead of the new account named tfsa$UNIQUE_ID ?

Comment: Are you trying to list containers immediately after creating the storage account?

Comment: @GauravMantri, yeah i've followed the tutorial, step-by-step... weirdly enough it works in Azure Cloud Shell.... but if i try and run the command on my local shell it produces that error.. updated description in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the command with debug:

`az storage container list --debug  --account-name tfsa$UNIQUE_ID   --query [].name   --output tsv`

I was able to see that it was setting it.

It turns out it had set the environment variable 'AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING' from a tutorial a few days ago, which was overriding a property when the command was sent, to use an old examples value.  After unsetting that environment variable, the command worked.